# Can not share new project with Subversive SVN in Eclipse Neon

Tags: eclipse, subversive, svnkit, eclipse-neon

I just downloaded a fresh Eclipse JEE Neon.1a Release (4.6.1) on my Windows 10 machine. 
I went to the marketplace to get the latest Subversive SVN Team Provider 4.0.2. 
Trying to install results in the Message: `The following solutions are not available: SVN Team Provider 4.0.2`.
I chose to continue anyways, and it seemed to work. 
After the restart, i chose the SVNKit 1.8.14 Subversive SVN Connector and installed without any issues.

Now I was able to do basic SVN operations, all seemed fine. 
Except to share a new project. I created a new Project called "test" and tried to share as a new project. 
That results in the Message:

> Share project was failed.
>   Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: URL 'http://sol:3380/svn/repo/test' non-existent in that revision.

I tried to share a new project to another SVN Server, same error message. 
I repeated the whole process on different machines, same message.

I Installed SVN Team Provider directly from the Update Site instead of the Marketplace. Same Issue.

I went to the SVNKit website to try older Versions of SVNKit and installed via the archived Update Sites, but they wont even show up in the SVN Connector Chooser in Eclipse.

I really dont know what to do anymore, can anyone help me to get it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I hope this solution will help you as it helped me. I think your problem is related to an unmatched client/server version. Neon subversive version is 4 and related svn connector is 1.8. But you probably need an svn connector 1.7 as it was in my case. Try the next steps and let me know if it works. Otherwise let me know the point in which you get in trouble.

1. go to help > installation details > filter by "svn" > uninstall everything related to subversive, subclipse and svn connectors
2. restart eclipse
3. to to help > install new software > work with > use the previous major subversive version from this URL: http://download.eclipse.org/technology/subversive/3.0/update-site/
4. install at least the plug-in and the integrations
5. restart eclipse
6. it will probably not ask you for a connector to be installed because you have already installed one previously, so go to window > preferences > team > svn > svn connector tab > get connectors > 1.7! (you can install all of them, the important thing is the one you choose in the combo box, it must be 1.7)
7. try the svn check-out process again

bye!

Comment: You saved my day! I installed directly fom the 3.0 update-site as you described. After that, it prompted me to install an SVNKit version. I even tried SVNKit 1.8.2, and everything works. I guess the problem is somewhere in the current `SVN Team Provider` update site 4.0. Again, many many thanks to you.

Comment: Thanks was the answer to my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41060611/bug-with-eclipse-subversive-update-sharing-a-new-project-into-repository-is-bro

Comment: I have started a bug report at https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508970 please vote it up!

Comment: Thanks for creating the bug report, JFK. You have my vote.

Answer (score 0):

Bug was fixed yesterday. So just update.

Comment: An Update did not work for me, but it works on a fresh install now. An install via the Marketplace still shows the Message: `The following solutions are not available: SVN Team Provider 4.0.2`, but it will work nontheless.

Comment: This bug still exists in neon.2.  There seems to be no way to install SVN support for eclipse via the market place. I dont know any other way, so I have to do all mySVN stuff outside eclipse which is a pain.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstalled the SVNKit 1.8.14, and it worked for me.