# Bug with Eclipse Subversive update: Sharing a New project into repository is broken

Tags: eclipse, svn, subversive

A recent prompt for an update by Eclipse Neon contained an update to subversive. It failed because the component was not available at the neon update site.
I therefore added [the recommended polarion connector update site](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive/download) and updated. 
I now have the following installed;

- Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
           Version: Neon.1a Release (4.6.1)
            Build id: 20161007-1200
- Subversive SVN Team Provider  4.0.2.I20160902-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group  Eclipse.org
- JavaHL 1.8.15 Win64 Binaries (Optional)   6.0.0.I20160427-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.javahl18.win64.feature.group    Polarion Software (interestingly this does not show up under the connectors group but sits at the top level )

I am running on Windows 7 x64

I also have svn command line installed on the client

- svn, version 1.9.4 (r1740329)
  compiled Apr 24 2016, 15:40:35 on x86-microsoft-windows

On the server we are running

- subversion 1.8.5

When I try and 'share' a new eclipse project into a standard layout SVN repoistory I now get the following (seemingly contardictory) errors;

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2016-12-09 10:53:11.642
!MESSAGE SVN: '0x00000121: Share Projects' operation finished with error
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2016-12-09 10:53:11.642
!MESSAGE Share project was failed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E160013: URL 'svn://svn.lan:3691/jf/trunk/Play' non-existent in that revision
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1541)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.list(SVNClientImpl.java:190)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector.listEntries(SVNKitConnector.java:1745)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.extension.factory.ThreadNameModifier.listEntries(ThreadNameModifier.java:323)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.list(SVNUtility.java:437)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnstorage.SVNRepositoryContainer.getChildren(SVNRepositoryContainer.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.local.management.ShareProjectOperation$1.run(ShareProjectOperation.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doSubTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:118)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:156)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.protectStep(AbstractActionOperation.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.local.management.ShareProjectOperation.runImpl(ShareProjectOperation.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.LoggedOperation.run(LoggedOperation.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.run(DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.SVNTeamOperationWrapper.run(SVNTeamOperationWrapper.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext.run(JobRunnableContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext$ResourceJob.runInWorkspace(JobRunnableContext.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E160013: URL 'svn://svn.lan:3691/jf/trunk/Play' non-existent in that revision
    at org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException.fromException(ClientException.java:117)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1540)
    ... 26 more
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnnature 4 0 2016-12-09 10:53:11.643
!MESSAGE Share project was failed.
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Can't overwrite cause with org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E170000: URL 'svn://svn.lan:3691/jf/trunk/Play' non-existent in revision 13
    at java.lang.Throwable.initCause(Throwable.java:457)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1541)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.info(SVNClientImpl.java:1739)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.info2(SVNClientImpl.java:1715)
    at org.polarion.team.svn.connector.svnkit.SVNKitConnector.getInfo(SVNKitConnector.java:1395)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.extension.factory.ThreadNameModifier.getInfo(ThreadNameModifier.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.SVNUtility.info(SVNUtility.java:470)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnstorage.SVNRepositoryContainer.getRevisionImpl(SVNRepositoryContainer.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnstorage.SVNRepositoryResource.getRevision(SVNRepositoryResource.java:97)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.svnstorage.SVNRepositoryResource.exists(SVNRepositoryResource.java:108)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.local.management.ShareProjectOperation.mkdir(ShareProjectOperation.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.local.management.ShareProjectOperation.runImpl(ShareProjectOperation.java:173)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.CompositeOperation.runImpl(CompositeOperation.java:99)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.AbstractActionOperation.run(AbstractActionOperation.java:82)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.operation.LoggedOperation.run(LoggedOperation.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTask(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:104)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.core.utility.ProgressMonitorUtility.doTaskExternal(ProgressMonitorUtility.java:90)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.run(DefaultCancellableOperationWrapper.java:55)
    at org.eclipse.team.svn.ui.utility.SVNTeamOperationWrapper.run(SVNTeamOperationWrapper.java:35)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext.run(JobRunnableContext.java:151)
    at org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.actions.JobRunnableContext$ResourceJob.runInWorkspace(JobRunnableContext.java:76)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.InternalWorkspaceJob.run(InternalWorkspaceJob.java:39)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException: svn: E170000: URL 'svn://svn.lan:3691/jf/trunk/Play' non-existent in revision 13
    at org.apache.subversion.javahl.ClientException.fromException(ClientException.java:117)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.javahl17.SVNClientImpl.getClientException(SVNClientImpl.java:1540)
    ... 26 more
```

Is anyone else experiencing similar issues?
( i have reported it to [Eclipse bugs](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=508970), it used to be the case that there was a Polarion bug tracker for connectors, but now [the new Siemens branded site](https://polarion.plm.automation.siemens.com/products/svn/subversive)'s BugTracker link just points back to the subversion section on Eclipse)
I have found the svn integration in eclipse to be increasingly problematic, is anyone else having the same problems and did they change over to anything else which was more successful?

---

I uninstalled the  JavaHL 1.8.15 Win64 Binaries as these have been problematic in the past, and restarted Eclipse. 
I check in preferences->Team->svn->Connectors 
and I am now using

- SVNKit 1.8.14 Implementation (Optional) 6.0.3.I20161124-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18.feature.group  Polarion Software

and getting more or less the same error

---

I uninstalled all of subversive and reinstalled it from the neon update site.

- Subversive Revision Graph (Optional) 4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.revision.graph.feature.group   Eclipse.org
- Subversive SVN Connectors    6.0.3.I20161124-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.feature.group   Polarion Software
- Subversive SVN Integration for the M2E Project (Optional)    4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.m2e.feature.group  Eclipse.org
- Subversive SVN Integration for the Mylyn Project (Optional)  4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.mylyn.feature.group    Eclipse.org
- Subversive SVN JDT Ignore Extensions (Optional)  4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.resource.ignore.rules.jdt.feature.group    Eclipse.org
- Subversive SVN Team Provider 4.0.2.I20160902-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.feature.group  Eclipse.org
- Subversive SVN Team Provider Localization (Optional) 4.0.0.I20160226-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.nl1.feature.group  Eclipse.org
- Subversive SVN Team Provider Sources  4.0.2.I20160902-1700    org.eclipse.team.svn.source.feature.group   Eclipse.org
- SVNKit 1.8.14 Implementation (Optional)  6.0.3.I20161124-1700    org.polarion.eclipse.team.svn.connector.svnkit18.feature.group  Polarion Software

Same problem...

---

Tried same operation 'manually' with

- TortoiseSVN 1.9.4, Build 27285 - 64 Bit , 2016/04/24 13:59:58
  Subversion 1.9.4, -release

Works fine

---

SO eventually showed me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984896/can-not-share-new-project-with-subversive-svn-in-eclipse-neon?rq=1). I followed the answer's instructions and now can share projects. Seems that the latest subversive versions do not work. Note that like the comments to the answer I also found that the 1.8 SVNKit connector worked (for svn 1.8+)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can not share new project with Subversive SVN in Eclipse Neon](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40984896/can-not-share-new-project-with-subversive-svn-in-eclipse-neon)